# Build a list in PHP from multiple selected form options

Tags: php

I have a form that a user completes to join a chat room, wasn't ever a problem as we only had it to be able to join a single chat room but now we've provided multiple options like

```
           <option value="#Chat1">Chat 1</option>
           <option value="#Chat2">Chat 2</option>
           <option value="#Chat3">Chat 3</option>
           <option value="#Chat4">Chat 4</option>
```

Later on I have

```
params.autojoin = "<? echo $_POST['channel']; ?>";
```

How can I change this so that it is every selected channel seperated by a comma i.e. `#Chat1,#Chat3`?

Thanks

Comment: you might need to have name attribute of select tag something like name='chatRoom[]' and then in php you can use implode as implode(',', $_POST['chatRoom'])

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<select name="chatRoom[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="#Chat1">Chat 1</option>
<option value="#Chat2">Chat 2</option>
<option value="#Chat3">Chat 3</option>
<option value="#Chat4">Chat 4</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**
    $selectChatRoom = implode(",",$_POST['chatRoom']);

Comment: I dont think this is the way to go. If you make the select into a multiple="multiple", it already is an 'array' that's posted (comma separted string, I believe) so you don't need the brackets

Comment: Its only an array if the name contains []. Otherwise, $_POST['chatRoom'] will only contain the last value.

Comment: @barryhunter you are right. but my point is that you need to add multiple="multiple" to the select. You can always make the posted value into an array through server side code...

Answer (score 0):

```
params.autojoin = "<? echo implode(',',$_POST['channel']); ?>";
```

Edit:

As others have commented, my solution assumes you have correctly set up your `select` like:

```
<select multiple name="channel[]">
```

You might already have this; no way to tell if you don't provide the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

set name of the select as name="channel[]"

```
params.autojoin = "<?php echo isset($_POST['channel']) && is_array($_POST['channel']) ? implode(',', $_POST['channel']) : ''; ?>";
```